# What address do I write in the Südtirol travel form when I'm changing location frequently (such as when backpacking)?

Tags: covid-19, italy

I am considering whether cycling from Germany to Italy may be feasible in the corona summer 2021 (fully vaccinated).  Tourism in Italy is presently allowed.  Among other questions, the [Südtirol registration form](https://siag.limequery.org/483785?lang.de) asks for the address where the visitor will reside.  What can I answer here if I am intending to be trekking, changing location (almost) every night?  When entering the United States or Russia (pre-corona), it was customary and accepted to write the address for the first night only.  Is this practice approved for the registration for entering Italy?

I haven't looked through the [EU Passenger Location Form](https://app.euplf.eu/) yet, but I expect there might be a similar question there (visitors to Südtirol need to complete both forms in any case).

Comment: My experience with PLF forms in other countries is that the most important part to enter is your mobile number. Make sure that is correct. Then just enter your stay.
They will just call you to check on you.

Answer (score 3):

I have almost the same issue for a planned trip to South Tyrol next week (I might stay at multiple places and perhaps not sure when entering Italy exactly where I will be staying) and I just called the information hotline mentioned at the beginning of the form.

If you know the first location you are planning to stay, you should enter that location, or at least an approximate. The address of stay is just a text field and you can also mention or explain there what you know when entering and that staying at further locations is planned, but you don't know exactly where.

Quite honestly, I doubt that this information will be used for anything particular at all.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately those forms are just security theater. No one takes contact tracing seriously in the EU.

Comment: @JonathanReez: That is certainly not true for Belgium. After filling out the PLF form I got called within hours of my arrival. Over the next few days I had several calls (and quite a few failed ones) from the contact tracing centre. Which is also why I remarked that the most important thing is that the telephone number you fill out is correct.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't know about Italy, but I would also dispute that there is no contact tracing done in the EU. In this case, I find it however odd that you have to fill out two different entry forms, both to the provincial authorities in South Tyrol and to the state authorities in Rome and on top of that, you also have to provide your data when actually staying at an accomodation. If there is a breakout at a hotel, I would very much assume that the hotel's visitor register is used to contact other guests and not the data in the entry forms.